# Error after installation of allure pytest adaptor

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I am trying to configure Allure (2.6.0) with Pytest (3.6xx) on a Windows 8 box. 
I am able to run pytest and generate jUnit xml report file which later I can pass to allure (allure server jUnitXmlFile.xml) and it works fine.

What I need is the additional functionality that Allure provides (metadata,attachments, etc), so I downloaded **pytest-allure-adaptor**.

So I have the following packages installed in my venv:

```
allure-pytest==2.4.1
allure-python-commons==2.4.1
pytest-allure-adaptor==1.7.10
...
```

If I now run py.test.exe, I get the following error:

```
(venv) c:\TestAutomation>py.test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tools\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in 
_run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Tools\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in 
_run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\TestAutomation\venv\Scripts\py.test.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in 
<module>
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 52, 
in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 
163, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 
617, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 
222, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 
216, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 
196, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 
68, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
 File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 76, 
in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
 File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 180, 
in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 
941, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
 File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 
1091, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 
1053, in _preparse
    self.pluginmanager.load_setuptools_entrypoints('pytest11')
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 
403, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
    self.register(plugin, name=ep.name)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 
260, in register
    ret = super(PytestPluginManager, self).register(plugin, name)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 
254, in register
    hook._maybe_apply_history(hookimpl)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 
650, in _maybe_apply_history
    res = self._hookexec(self, [method], kwargs)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 
222, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 
216, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 
201, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 76, 
in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 
180, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\allure_pytest\plugin.py", 
line 20, in pytest_addoption
   help="Generate Allure report in the specified directory (may not exist)")
  File "c:\testautomation\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 
759, in addoption
    raise ValueError("option names %s already added" % conflict)
 ValueError: option names {'--alluredir'} already added
```

Is there something wrong with the **pytest-allure-adaptor** ?
Anyone have similar problems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*allure-python-commons* is incompatible with *pytest-allure-adaptor*. You need to remove old plugin and reinstall *allure-pytest* and *allure-python-commons*.

Comment: Removing pytest-allure-adaptor module solves the problem. Thanks for the justification.

Answer (score 0):

Your pytest-allure-adaptor is incompatible. Only thing is required to run this pip command if you have python2-

```
pip uninstall pytest-allure-adaptor
```

else run this command if you have python3 -

```
pip3 uninstall pytest-allure-adaptor
```