# Allure ModuleNotFoundError but only on certain functions of the package

Tags: python, selenium, testing, report, allure

I am starting to work with Allure to make reports for my test automation team. My goal is to attach screenshots but I run into an error. The lines of code that prompt this error are:

```
import allure #This line runs fine
from allure.constants import AttachmentType #This one throws the error
```

Which throws: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allure.constants'; 'allure' is not a package`

I am using allure throughout different parts of the code without running into errors, for example I use the decorator:

```
@allure.step("Description of a step")
```

So the module is being correctly loaded. Upon further inspection on the internet I found links stating that I should uninstall previous packages such as **pytest-allure-adaptor** as seen in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934480/error-after-installation-of-allure-pytest-adaptor). I did so but the error remains unchanged.

In order to give more context, I am using the following softaware:

IDE: Visual Studio Code
OS: Windows 7
Python version: 3.6
allure-pytest: 2.8.12
allure-python-commons: 2.8.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in the version of allure that I was using allure.constants does not exist.

I solved my problem my changing that line to:

```
from allure import attachment_type
```

And then, to take the screenshot and adding it to the report:

```
allure.attach('screenshot', driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), type=attachment_type.PNG)
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future.